# Make onclick function work with ENTER and "Go" button on Safari Mobile (iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events, buttonclick

I have a form in which the button calls a function `onclick`:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute();" value="Go">
</form>

function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
      var end = "My Address in Rome";
      var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
      };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
}
```

It works properly on every browser if you click on the <kbd>Go</kbd> button (`<input type="button">`). It doesn't if I fill the `<input type="text">` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on my keyboard (or for example push the <kbd>Go</kbd> button in iOS keyboard). So: it works if I push the `input type="button"`, not if I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from keyboard. How can I make it work that way too?

EDIT: Not jQuery or other framework please. :)

Comment: Why aren't you using a submit button and why are you using inline javascript?

Comment: Uhm, also if I change it to `<input type="submit">` still doesn't work. What do you mean by inline js? :)

Comment: He means `onclick="calcRoute();"`. This is frowned upon for similar reasons as inline styles. We avoid inline javascript by binding event handlers in our window load, or if using jquery, document ready. But we ought to be here to answer your question more than we are here to critique your code style.

Answer (score 3):

You should really just remove that inline javascript and make that button into a real submit button. After that you can easily capture the form being submitted (wether be enter key or by submit button):

```
form.addEventListener('submit', calcRoute);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ghK4P/

Comment: I tried (here's the demo with your code): http://ffio.it/test.html
Click on "calcola percorso". When you type an address it should build the route. Nothing happens... :)

Comment: You have overwritten the function `calcRoute()`. Just add the `e.preventDefault()` to your own function and don't forget to add the `e` as an argument.

Comment: Also in your specific case you would rather want to do `var form = document.getElementbyId('percorsoform');`

Comment: Here I put your code within the existing function calcRoute(): http://ffio.it/test2.html

Comment: No that part you should have left where it was. I was talking about the part with `e.preventDefault();` in it.

Comment: See my previous comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263331/make-onclick-function-work-with-enter-and-go-button-on-safari-mobile-ios/16263462?noredirect=1#comment23272457_16263462

Comment: Typo sorry. It should have been `getElementById` with an uppercase B

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16263930/1342772 If you help me converting it to not-inline javascript I'll accept your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<form onsubmit="calcRoute()">
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute();" value="Go">
</form>
```

i'm sure it'll work with both

Comment: Uhm, no :'(. The form is submitted to the server that way (and in URL I have `?start=INPUT_TEXT`

Comment: i dont know what you're trying to do and hence cant answer properly but try: <form onsubmit="return calcRoute()">

Comment: Uhm, no. Same behaviour. Here's the demo: goo.gl/wr3qi , click on "calcola percorso". :)

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno i have posted another answer check it out

Answer (score 0):

Probably add this in your code if you using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#start").bind('keyup',function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#start").click();
    }
});
});
```

it will trigger ur button click function on pressing enter key in your text box.

If you not using jquery try this one

```
<input type="text" id="start" name="start" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('fire_calRoute').click()">
<input type="button" id='fire_calRoute' onclick="calcRoute();" value="Go">
```

try this, hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="start" name="start" onkeypress="return calcRoute(event)">
```

now modify your script as follows:

```
function calcRoute(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell what are you expecting and what you are getting?

Comment: It should work like this (type an address of Rome and push the "Go" button): http://goo.gl/wr3qi

Comment: can you tell me some address in Rome so that i can test it?

Comment: Yup, sorry :D Try with "Via Eugenio Checchi, Roma"

Comment: It is if you type that address and push "Vai" (Go) button

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

```
<form onsubmit="calcRoute(); return false">
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    <input type="submit" value="Vai">
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any solution without using form tag?